# Error in tomcat in creation of web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat7, apache-axis, eclipse-juno

I created simple addition of two number web services by using bottom up approach by using Axis 2 in eclipse juno.Web services working correctly and properly tested by soa client mozilla extension but there is error in tomcat.Please go through below error

he Calculator service, which is not valid, caused

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/Produces
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxrs.JAXRSUtils.getClassModel(JAXRSUtils.java:53)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:272)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:468)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:388)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:283)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.Produces
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 30 more

[INFO] org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/Produces
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/M:/mahesh/work/javaws1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Calc/WEB-INF/services/version.aar
[WARN] No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your axis2.xml file!
```

Comment: Calculator service is not valid nor your formatting, try to improve it

Comment: Sorry for my formatting.I will try to improve it.Please help me out.

Comment: Why i get below error as Calculator service is properly working and client also receives correct result.
The Calculator service, which is not valid, caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/Produces

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is just a servlet container and AFAIK, it does not support any kind of webservices by default.

You have to have the required libraries in your WEB-INF/lib or add it to tomcat lib folder and make use of it.

you are getting ClassNotFoundException as javax/ws/rs/Produces is not found in the classpath.

Deploy the REST implementation (Ex: Jersey) to server lib and restart your server.

Comment: I didn't use rest api.For web services i use Axis2.

Comment: Irrespective of the webservices implementation, if you are using any technology other than basic servlet and jsp, you have to provide the library to tomcat. This is clearly reflecting in the error message as the error is ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Same for me, As i am using SOAP ws, then why we are facing this error. anybody ?

Comment: Add the required jars to your WEB-INF/lib or to tomcat lib folder.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan :- I added jsr311-api-0.10 to my lib folder.Now error become

The Calc service, which is not valid, caused Two services cannot have same name.  A service with the calc [file:/M:/mahesh/work/javaws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Calc/WEB-INF/services/Calc/] name already exists in the system.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Two services cannot have same name.  A service with the calc [file:/M:/mahesh/work/javaws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Calc/WEB-INF/services/Calc/] name already exists in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing annotations in your Axis2 service class. In our case, removing @Deprecated solved the error.